# How to set value to TextView from class which is out of activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, textview

How to set value to TextView from class which is out of activity? The value we get at an undetermined time, so it is important to set the value from that class.

All advice would be helpful. Thank you.

P.S.:

For example, in Actvity I have method, which sets the value to a TextView.

```
public void textViewSetText (String value){
    tv.setText(value);    
} //how correctly to transfer value from my class to get the desired effect?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have hold of your Activity, then its not possible because TextView is available in Activity. So when you dont have reference to activity, you cant alter it's contents too. In case you pass your activity reference to a static method, then its possible for that method to do the modifications.

Comment: For example, in Actvity I have method, which sets the value to a TextView. public void tvTwoThreadTimeSetText (String value){
  tv.setText(value);           //how correctly to transfer value from my class to get the desired effect

Comment: nop, you cant transfer this value without using activity reference. But if you employ some BroadcastReceiver, then you can do this by using application's context (no activity required)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the content of TextView should only be set inside a activity. Though you can set that value outside of the activity, it is not quite useful.

As for your question, you got the value at an undetermined time, there are some choices.For example, you can register a callback to that class, and when the other class got that value, you can send a message through that callback. But be careful about the threading problem, setting a value to a TextView is a UI operation, which should only be done in a UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread
2. `AsyncTask` allows you to perform asynchronous work on your user interface. It performs the blocking operations in a worker thread and then publishes the results on the UI thread, without requiring you to handle threads and/or handlers yourself.

Here is an example:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new SomeTask().execute(something);
    }
    private class SomeTask extends AsyncTask<Something, Void, String> {
        /** The system calls this to perform work in a worker thread and
          * delivers it the parameters given to AsyncTask.execute() */
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Something something) {
            return string; // the TextView's text
        }

        /** The system calls this to perform work in the UI thread and delivers
          * the result from doInBackground() */
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            textView.setText(result);
        }
    }
```

However, if you don't give your case more detailed, no exact answer may satisfy you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external Static Class to save the value of the String to modify (and set the value once you return to your TextView_Class), only access to the Static Class to get the value.

You may also save the "this" (Activity) in the Static Class and access to that Activity from everywhere, so you can modify the TextView. (I don't thinks this would be recommended).

Depending the case (you didnt explained enought), the normal thing to do is to Bundle the String if they're parent-child classes.

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure about your question but
try like this may be it will work

```
((MainActivity) activity).textViewSetText();

public void textViewSetText (String value){

    tv.setText(value);    
}
```

but your activity have to extends The MainActivity.